# Python methods calling other methods from another class

Tags: python, function, class

I might have a simple question for some of you but I couldnt find this exact topic in the forum.

In this simple example I have two classes `class mainTest()` & `class mainTest2():`

Essentially I am trying to call the `dosomething(self):` method in the second class from the first class, but the issue that I am having is when the `dosomething` method is calling a secondary method from the second class, with the following error message:

---

```
class mainTest():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
    def runsomething(self):
        mainTest2.dosomething(self)


class mainTest2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 1
        self.d = 2
    def dosomething(self):
        self.dosomethingelse()

    def dosomethingelse(self):
        print(self.d)

t=mainTest()
#set class variable by first method

t.runsomething()
```

---

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'mainTest' object has no attribute 'dosomethingelse'
```

---

What I tried to do is instead of calling `self.dosomethingelse(self)` I called `mainTest2.dosomethingelse(self)`

---

```
class mainTest2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 1
        self.d = 2
    def dosomething(self):
        mainTest2.dosomethingelse(self)

    def dosomethingelse(self):
        print(self.d)
```

---

But I get the following error:

```
'mainTest' object has no attribute 'd'
```

I know this might be pretty obvious but Im just a beginner.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `class mainTest2(mainTest)`?

Comment: It is simple. The error message is pretty clear, "'mainTest' object has no attribute 'dosomethingelse'". The object you passed to that function is a `mainTest` object. It doesn't have the attribute `dosomethingelse`. Why did you expect it to?

Comment: It's a lot easier to explain why what you are doing is wrong when the functions actually *do* something. In this abstract example, all we can do is explain why it's failing mechanically. You say you want to call `dosomething` from a `mainTest` method: why?

Comment: It is not obvious, until you *really* need understand the concepts of classes and instances (and the related aspects of attributes and methods), which also brings to the knowledge of [the meaning of `self`](//stackoverflow.com/q/2709821). Remember that `mainTest2` is a **class**: when you do `mainTest2.dosomething(self)` you're using it as a standard function, telling `dosomething()` that its `self` argument is the *instance* of `mainTest` (referenced as `t` later in your code), so you're practically trying to call `t.dosomethingelse()`, which will fail since it has no such attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `t.runsomething()`, that passes `self` to `mainTest2.dosomething(self)` however, that `self` is of type `mainTest` so when you run `mainTest2.dosomething(self)` and it calls `self.dosomethingelse()` the `self` here is what you passed in ie "type of `mainTest` and that type has no method `dosomethingelse()`

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your original definition of `mainTest2`; the definition of `mainTest1` is doing something fundamentally wrong.

In your first example, you are calling a *function* that expects an instance of `mainTest2` with an argument of type `mainTest`. Instances of `mainTest` don't have the `dosomethingelse` method expected by `dosomething`.

In the second example, you are just passing that same instance of `mainTest` that `mainTest2.dosomething` received and passing it to a *different* function that expects an argument of type `mainTest2`. Just as before, that argument is lacking an expected attribute, this time `d` instead of `dosomethingelse`.

Instance methods are not intended to be invoked as regular functions with explicit instance arguments. They are intended to be invoked on the instance itself. It's hard to correct `mainTest`, because what it's doing is *fundamentally* wrong. You don't have an instance of `mainTest2` available, so you have no business trying to call `mainTest2.dosomethingelse`.